# rails 3, how to route a find_or_create_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a find_or_create_by:

```
def create
     @code = Code.find_by_code(params[:redemption][:code])
     @redemption = @code.redemptions.find_or_create_by_user_id(current_user.id) 
      if @redemption.save
        redirect_to bands_url, :notice => "Redemption Successful."
      else
        redirect_to bands_url, :notice  => "Could not redeem code"
      end
  end
```

If a user "redeems" a code once, the code works fine.  IF they try to redeem the same code again, it still gives the notice "Redemption Successful"... I assume this is because it found a @code.redemption...  How can I make it so that if it creates a redemption, it says "Redemption Successful" even though a new redemption is not created... It simply found it.  I'd like to say: "Redemption already used"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of find_or_create_by, you could do the following:

```
@redemption = @code.redemptions.find_or_initialize_by_user_id(current_user.id)
if @redemption.new_record? && @redemption.save
  redirect_to bands_url, :notice => "Redemption Successful."
else
  redirect_to bands_url, :notice => "Could not redeem code."
end
```

That way, you can determine if it's a new record (initialize_by) or an existing record (find)